# Skyrmions - Solving a second-order nonlinear ODE with a singularity on x=0

Tags: computational-physics, differential-equations

I'm doing some reasearch on electromagnetic nanostructures (on skyrmions) and I have to solve this differential equation (the exact values of the constants don't matter, I just want **all** the possible solutions of y(x) given some values to these constants).

$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\sin(2y)}{2} (\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{K}{A})-\frac{D}{A}\frac{\sin(y)}{x}+\frac{\mu HM}{2A}\sin(y)
$$

from x=0 till x=R, with the boundary conditions

$$
y(0)=0,\ \frac{dy}{dx}(R)=\frac{-D}{2A}
$$

I believe you can not find an analitic solution to this equation, so I've been trying to use numerical methods like the shooting method (given the boundary conditions, I found it appropiate).

The thing is that the singularity on x=0 doesn't let me find the solutions. I obtain different results depending on how many steps I take in the method.

I also posted this on [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25543/solving-a-second-order-nonlinear-ode-with-a-singularity-on-x-0) and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010468/solving-a-second-order-nonlinear-ode-with-a-singularity-on-x-0) StackExchange, but for now I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble with equations like that, too. Mathematica can solve this numerically, but it's pretty ugly and I was faced with the same problem. There is usually no analytical solution in Skyrme eqs.

I had the boundary cond. $y(0)=\pi, y(\infty)=0$ and used a Relaxation Method (in C...should be also in Mathematica) based on the transformation $x\to\tan(z)$, then $y(x)\to f(z)$, $y'(x)\to\cos^2(z)f'(z)$ and so on. In your case, I don't really get why you have $y'(R)$ given. Perhaps you should try the Relaxation method, it's also faster but needs more input. Or you try to estimate your initial cond. by a Taylor expansion in y(0).